# jQuery - show the content of a div by a link without id/class references

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
function showContent() {
    ...
}

<div id="example">
    content
    <a href="#" onClick="showContent();return false">Link</a>
</div>
```

I'd like, when I click on the **Link**, show the *content* of the div, without using id or class as reference, but (maybe) the simple *this*.

How can I do it?

Comment: How is the content hidden?  "display:none"?  Also, is all the content under a single node next to the <a>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's not a whole lot of context, but this is one way:

```
<div id="example">
 <p style="display: none;">content</p>
 <a href="#" onClick="showContent(this);return false">Show content above</a>
</div>

function showContent(el) {
    $(el).parent().children(':first-child').show();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LeVFb/

Or, if you wanted to show all within (and I don't think the `:not` really matters* in this case):

```
function showContent(el) {
    $(el).parent().children(':not(a)').show();
}
```

*In fact, I would go ahead and say leave it off unless you have a specific reason not to:

```
function showContent(el) {
    $(el).parent().children().show();
}
```

It would depend on the content you're trying to display and whether any A tags are `display: hidden` and need to be shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/LeVFb/2/

This could go a number of ways.

Comment: In fact that a link is into other divs. So I've done this `$(el).parents('#example').html();` : what do you think about? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to wrap the "content" in a `<div>` (or some other block element):

```
<div id="example">
    <div style="display: none;">content</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showContent(this)">Link</a>
</div>
```

And don't use `href="#"` for these sorts of links, `href="javascript:void(0)"` is a better choice that causes fewer problems; the `void(0)` approach also means that you don't need `return false` in your click handler to keep the browser from trying to interpret an empty fragment.

Back to our regularly scheduled program. Then, your `showContent` becomes quite simple:

```
function showContent(e) {
    $(e).prev('div').show();
}
```

A better way is to use jQuery to bind the click handler:

```
<div id="example">
    <div style="display: none;">content</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
</div>
```

And then:

```
$('#example a').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('div').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jquery [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector

```
$(this).parent('div').show()
```

However, how is the link visible, if the containing div is not?

Answer (score 0):

If the link is within the div, you could do this...

```
<a href="#" onClick="showContent(this);return false">Link</a>
```

then in your function...

```
function showContent(link){
     alert($(link).parent().html());
}
```

However, this assumes that the div is visible already so you wouldn't need to "show" it.